# Is there a term for a meaning that is wrong or different but about to be accepted by the majority?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, terminology

It's about the ***Speedpaint*** thing. For example a speedpaint video that shows a sped up progress of a drawing using Photoshop. I've got into discussions with people claiming *speedpaint* is a wrong term for recorded digital drawings that are sped up, so instead they call it a *time-lapse* video.

Speedpaint normally is used for a drawing technique that is drawn in real time but quickly executed within a determined time.

But a lot of digital artists use this term for semantic and pandering reasons in time-lapse videos like on YouTube for tags etc. And it's in the process of being accepted by the majority or at least by the target audience who is familiar with digital art since it's becoming a common term even if it's originally different/wrong.

And with *wrong* I mean that when a term has a new meaning due to new technology/trend/culture etc and therefore the old meaning becomes irrelevant.

I was explaining this in some discussions but I couldn't express myself enough without knowing the term. Any help?

*Sorry for my bad English, feel free to edit my question.*

Comment: How can something that's understood by the majority ever be wrong? Unless you're talking about something that means one thing to one group and something different to a different group. That's *domain-specific* meaning.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Speedpaint literally means drawing quickly within a set time but today it becomes common that this word is being used for paint videos recorded in a time-lapse. That's why it's usually considered wrong. Exactly this is what I would like to know if there exists a term for it. Excuse my bad English. And yes it's maybe for one group common and for the other not, which could be those who don't accept it in the mainstream (yet). My bad it's hard to explain. I edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: Yes, I understand that's what it might mean to those people who use it that way. But if a large number of people take it to mean something *else*, then it also *does* mean something else—for those other people. It's no different than a single word in the dictionary having a many different senses. Context determines meaning. And just because one context is different from another, that doesn't mean that it's being used *incorrectly* in the other context. When a word has a specific meaning in a specific area, then that meaning is said to be specific to that particular domain.

Comment: A speedpaint is a hyponym of a timelapse. Timelapses aren't _exclusively_ speedpaints.

Answer (score 2):

Consider calling it a *misnomer*.

> **misnomer** *noun*
>   1 A wrong or inaccurate name or designation.
>   ‘morning sickness is a misnomer for many women, since the nausea can occur any time during the day’
>   [- lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/misnomer)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misnomer) notes that:

> A misnomer is a name that is incorrectly applied to a thing. Misnomers often arise because something was named long before its correct nature was known, or because an earlier form of something has been replaced by something to which the name no longer applies.

In your example, *speedpaint* is a *misnomer* because the video might not be about painting. The term *time-lapse* works more generally because it refers to the video production technique rather than the 'painting' technique.

Note that *misnomers* don't need to be a term misused by the *majority* (so perhaps doesn't exactly address your question). They just need to be inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks this goes in the right direction but there is one thing that the meaning is in the process of change and about to be recognised in the mainstream even if it had a different purpose.